# Fabric.js loadFromJSON is not working with rgba fill

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

I have a simple canvas on which I am adding shapes (triangle, circle, rectangle). I have used spectrum color picker which supports rgba and I am setting the fill of the shapes as per color selected. To this point everything works fine. Now I am exporting the canvas as JSON,

```
var json = JSON.stringify(canvas);
console.log(json);
```

This JSON output will be saved to the database later but for testing purpose I am copying the json from console and using it as follow,

```
canvas.loadFromJSON('{"objects":[{"type":"circle","originX":"center","originY":"center","left":400,"top":200,"width":100,"height":100,"fill":{"_originalInput":{"h":"0%","s":"100%","v":"100%","a":0.13},"_r":255,"_g":0,"_b":0,"_a":0.13,"_roundA":0.13,"_format":"rgb","_ok":true,"_tc_id":3288},"stroke":{"_originalInput":{"h":"0%","s":"0%","v":"0%","a":1},"_r":0,"_g":0,"_b":0,"_a":1,"_roundA":1,"_format":"rgb","_ok":true,"_tc_id":3783},"strokeWidth":1,"strokeDashArray":null,"strokeLineCap":"butt","strokeLineJoin":"miter","strokeMiterLimit":10,"scaleX":1,"scaleY":1,"angle":0,"flipX":false,"flipY":false,"opacity":0.4,"shadow":null,"visible":true,"clipTo":null,"backgroundColor":"","fillRule":"nonzero","globalCompositeOperation":"source-over","transformMatrix":null,"skewX":0,"skewY":0,"radius":50,"startAngle":0,"endAngle":6.283185307179586},{"type":"triangle","originX":"left","originY":"top","left":583,"top":89,"width":50,"height":50,"fill":{"_originalInput":{"h":"17.374213836477992%","s":"86.88524590163934%","v":"95.68627450980392%","a":0.34},"_r":235.01046366720004,"_g":243.98400000000004,"_b":32.01070080000003,"_a":0.34,"_roundA":0.34,"_format":"hex","_ok":true,"_tc_id":2503},"stroke":"rgb(0, 0, 0)","strokeWidth":6,"strokeDashArray":null,"strokeLineCap":"butt","strokeLineJoin":"miter","strokeMiterLimit":10,"scaleX":1,"scaleY":1,"angle":0,"flipX":false,"flipY":false,"opacity":1,"shadow":null,"visible":true,"clipTo":null,"backgroundColor":"","fillRule":"nonzero","globalCompositeOperation":"source-over","transformMatrix":null,"skewX":0,"skewY":0},{"type":"rect","originX":"left","originY":"top","left":485,"top":196,"width":50,"height":50,"fill":"#1d128f","stroke":null,"strokeWidth":1,"strokeDashArray":null,"strokeLineCap":"butt","strokeLineJoin":"miter","strokeMiterLimit":10,"scaleX":1,"scaleY":1,"angle":0,"flipX":false,"flipY":false,"opacity":0.4,"shadow":null,"visible":true,"clipTo":null,"backgroundColor":"","fillRule":"nonzero","globalCompositeOperation":"source-over","transformMatrix":null,"skewX":0,"skewY":0,"rx":0,"ry":0}],"background":""}');
canvas.renderAll();
```

The problem I am facing is that as the exported JSON has rgba values so when the shapes are rendered on canvas then the fill is black. The canvas is ignoring the rgba value present in the JSON string.

However when I use the following JSON string (which has the fill 'green' and 'red') then the shapes are rendered fine with color green and red.

```
canvas.loadFromJSON('{"objects":[{"type":"rect","left":50,"top":50,"width":20,"height":20,"fill":"green","overlayFill":null,"stroke":null,"strokeWidth":1,"strokeDashArray":null,"scaleX":1,"scaleY":1,"angle":0,"flipX":false,"flipY":false,"opacity":1,"selectable":true,"hasControls":true,"hasBorders":true,"hasRotatingPoint":false,"transparentCorners":true,"perPixelTargetFind":false,"rx":0,"ry":0},{"type":"circle","left":100,"top":100,"width":100,"height":100,"fill":"red","overlayFill":null,"stroke":null,"strokeWidth":1,"strokeDashArray":null,"scaleX":1,"scaleY":1,"angle":0,"flipX":false,"flipY":false,"opacity":1,"selectable":true,"hasControls":true,"hasBorders":true,"hasRotatingPoint":false,"transparentCorners":true,"perPixelTargetFind":false,"radius":50}],"background":"rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)"}');
```

Is this a bug in fabric.js or there is something which I am doing wrong?

Comment: In your loadFromJSON call you seem to be passing `fill` an object.  Per the [docs](http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.Object.html#fill), I believe it expects some sort of color string.  You might want to check your implementation.

Comment: @Ben the JSON that I have used in this code was generated by Fabric.js itself. So it is not that I am loading JSON from another source into the Fabric.js. So if Fabric.js has exported this JSON then it should be able to load it too. If Fabric.js does not support hsv and rgba then why it has included these while exporting the JSON?

Comment: Do you have a jsfiddle or something of it to look at?

Comment: @Ben I found that it is not the problem with Farbic but the problem with my complete code. I am posting my mistake as answer here so if someone make this mistake as I did is able to solve this issue.

Answer (score 1):

OK. I have found out why it is happening. The problem is how I am setting the color for shape objects. I am using Spectrum color picker and using following code to initialize the Spectrum and also adding code that when a color is selected on spectrum colorpicker then it is also changed for the selected shape object on canvas.

```
$(".spectrumColor").spectrum({
        showAlpha: true,
        showButtons: false,
        showPalette: true,
        palette: defaultPallete,
        allowEmpty: true,
        showInput: true,
        move: function (color) {

            var selectedObject = canvas.getActiveObject();
            if (selectedObject != null) {
                if ($(this).attr('id') == "FillColor") {
                    selectedObject.set('fill', color);
                    canvas.renderAll();
                }
                else if ($(this).attr('id') == "StrokeColor") {
                    selectedObject.set('stroke', color);
                    canvas.renderAll();
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

Here the problem is with this line,

```
selectedObject.set('stroke', color);
```

I have passed the whole color object from spectrum to the Fabric shape object. When I check the value of color in console then it is simple rgb string "rgb(255, 0, 0)" but when the complete object is assigned to the Fabric's shape object then it is adding hsv (hue, saturation, and lightness) string along with RGB to the Fabric shape object like this,

```
fill":{"_originalInput":{"h":"0%","s":"100%","v":"100%","a":0.13},"_r":255,"_g":0,"_b":0,"_a":0.13
```

As HSV is not recognizable by Fabric.js so it is rendering the shape objects in black color. To solve this I had to replace,

```
    selectedObject.set('stroke', color);
```

with

```
    selectedObject.set('stroke', color.toRgbString());
```

Comment: You should also be able to create a `new fabric.Color(color)` then use the `toRgb()` method to convert it to the proper color recognized by fabric.